# Multiple entries into mastersheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

Currently I'm inputting data into 3 cells and pressing a button which then transfers the data into a mastersheet. In my code, currently one click equals one entry. I'd like to have an option though for multiple entries per click depending on a value in a field. I've added the field but I'm just not sure how to code it. Any suggestions?

This is what the entry page looks like
[image: This is what the entry page looks like]

This is the mastersheet it writes to
[image: This is the mastersheet it writes to]

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim s1, s2
Set s1 = Worksheets("Master")
Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    .Cells(, "a").Value = s2.Range("p20").Value
    .Cells(, "b").Value = s2.Range("p21").Value
    .Cells(, "c").Value = s2.Range("c4").Value
    .Cells(, "d").Value = s2.Range("c7").Value
    .Cells(, "e").Value = s2.Range("c10").Value
    s2.Range("c4").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    s2.Range("c7").FormulaR1C1 = ""
    s2.Range("c10").FormulaR1C1 = ""

End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant but easy to implement:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet, i As Integer, LpCount As Integer
Set s1 = Worksheets("Master")
Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
If Not s2.Range("I7").Value > 1 Then LpCount = 1 Else LpCount = s2.Range("I7").Value

For i = 1 To LpCount
    With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
        .Cells(, "a").Value = s2.Range("p20").Value
        .Cells(, "b").Value = s2.Range("p21").Value
        .Cells(, "c").Value = s2.Range("c4").Value
        .Cells(, "d").Value = s2.Range("c7").Value
        .Cells(, "e").Value = s2.Range("c10").Value
    End With
Next i
s2.Range("c4").FormulaR1C1 = ""
s2.Range("c7").FormulaR1C1 = ""
s2.Range("c10").FormulaR1C1 = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey O.PAL thanks for the comment. I get a run-time error though when trying to run this code. Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: Should be fixed, sorry about that

Comment: That works so well O.PAL thank you so much! Is there a way for me to have it default I7 to 1 if there is no value present?

Comment: Actually I figured it out using FormulaR1C1. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Worksheets("Master")
Set s2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 1 To s2.Range("I7").Value
With s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    .Cells(, "a").Value = s2.Range("p20").Value
    .Cells(, "b").Value = s2.Range("p21").Value
    .Cells(, "c").Value = s2.Range("c4").Value
    .Cells(, "d").Value = s2.Range("c7").Value
    .Cells(, "e").Value = s2.Range("c10").Value

End With
Next i
s2.Range("c4").FormulaR1C1 = ""
s2.Range("c7").FormulaR1C1 = ""
s2.Range("c10").FormulaR1C1 = ""
s2.Range("i7").FormulaR1C1 = "1"


End Sub
```